# using a Michaelis-Menten curve, how do I calculate the critical value of each cultivar, and how do I test if they are significantly different?

Tags: r

I am trying to use a Michaelis-Menten curve in R to predict the amount of phosphorus needed to achieve 90 % of maximum yield (i.e. critical value). Furthermore, I would like to somehow test if the critical value is statistically different between cultivars. I might not have enough data points to be accurate but I still want to have a go.

This is the Michaelis Menton equation....

[image: Mechaelic Menton equation]

where v  is the reaction rate of product [P]  to substrate [S] , V_{max}  represents the maximum rate achieved by the system, and K_M  is the substrate concentration at which the reaction rate is half of V_{max} . TMy data is fitting a Michaelis-Menten curve to data using the drc package for R available in CRAN.

Here is my dput data set....

```
structure(list(cultivar = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Dinninup", 
"Riverina", "Seaton Park", "Yarloop"), class = "factor"), P = c(12.1, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 
48.35, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 
18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 
48.35, 48.35, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 
48.35, 48.35, 48.35), shoot = c(1.24, 1.12, 1.28, 1.28, 1.37, 
1.4, 1.39, 1.34, 1.34, 1.53, 1.25, 1.4, 1.44, 1.83, 1.65, 1.71, 
1.52, 1.75, 1.63, 1.7, 1.23, 1.22, 1.26, 0.89, 1.2, 1.55, 1.4, 
1.19, 1.75, 1.92, 1.63, 1.64, 1.34, 1.54, 1.66, 1.88, 1.9, 2.18, 
2.03, 1.68, 0.9, 1.49, 1.41, 1.57, 0.94, 1.83, 1.6, NA, 1.98, 
2.04, 1.64, 1.71, 1.97, 1.97, 1.87, 2.21, 2.1, 2.25, 2.1, 2.24, 
1.23, 1.32, 1.47, 1.54, 1.38, 1.09, 1.41, NA, 1.23, 1.14, 1.63, 
1.61, 1.42, 1.12, 1.74, 1.89, 1.4, 1.58, 1.71, 1.64)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 
56L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 
109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 
128L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 149L, 150L, 
151L, 152L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L))
```

in order to put all my cultivars on a ggplot with a fitted Michaelis-Menten curve for each culitvar, I first subsetted each cultivar

```
`yar <- subset(isosub,isosub$cultivar=='Yarloop')
din <- subset(isosub,isosub$cultivar=='Dinninup')
seat <- subset(isosub,isosub$cultivar=='Seaton Park')
riv <- subset(isosub,isosub$cultivar=='Riverina')`
```

I then put in the code for creating the lines for each cultivar which can be plotted in ggplot...

```
library(drc)

`m1 <- drm(shoot ~ P, data = yar, fct = MM.2())
mm1 <- data.frame(P = seq(0, max(yar$P), length.out = 100))
mm1$shoot <- predict(m1, newdata = mm1)
m2 <- drm(shoot ~ P, data = din, fct = MM.2())
mm2 <- data.frame(P = seq(0, max(din$P), length.out = 100))
mm2$shoot <- predict(m2, newdata = mm2)
m3 <- drm(shoot ~ P, data = seat, fct = MM.2())
mm3 <- data.frame(P = seq(0, max(seat$P), length.out = 100))
mm3$shoot <- predict(m3, newdata = mm3)
m4 <- drm(shoot ~ P, data = riv, fct = MM.2())
mm4 <- data.frame(P = seq(0, max(seat$P), length.out = 100))
mm4$shoot <- predict(m4, newdata = mm4)`
```

I then created the ggplot....

```
library(Rmisc)library(ggplot2)
```

like this

```
`tgp <- summarySE(isosub, measurevar="shoot", groupvars=c("P","cultivar"),na.rm = TRUE)
 ggplot(tgp, aes(x = P, y = shoot)) +
 geom_point(aes(shape=cultivar,colour=cultivar),size=4)+
 theme_bw() +
 scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),limits=c(0, 2.5),breaks=0:11*0.5)+
 xlab(expression(P~(mg~kg^-1~soil)))+
 ylab(expression(Shoot~dry~weight~(g~pot^-1)))+
 ggtitle("Michaelis-Menten") +
 geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
 geom_line(data = mm1, aes(x = P, y = shoot), colour = "purple")+
 geom_line(data = mm2, aes(x = P, y = shoot), colour = "pink")+
 geom_line(data = mm3, aes(x = P, y = shoot), colour = "blue")+
 geom_line(data = mm4, aes(x = P, y = shoot), colour = "green")+
 theme(legend.position = c(.8, .2))+
 guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL))+
 theme(legend.key.size = unit(6, "mm"))`
```

[image: graph]

So now the question is, how do I calculate the critical value of each cultivar, and how do I test if they are significantly different?

Here is an emample from a published paper...

[image: Published example]

and the table with the data that I need for my graph....

[image: example data needed]

I have calculted the critical value (CV) which is appernelty just 0.9 of KM.

```
`m1= Yarloop (CV =103.365) `
`m2= Dinninup (CV=56.862)` 
 m3= Seaton Park (CV=29.592)
m4= Riverina (CV=103.257)
```

So what I have to do now is find out how to test if these values are statistically different from each other...

Here is the methods used by one paper which calculated if the critical values in the example above (Fig 1) are statistically different...

*"The critical external P requirement of each species
was defined as the amount of P applied to achieve 90 %
of maximum yield. Estimates and confidence intervals
for critical P and maximumyield (a) were determined by
least squares and assume that the model is approximately
linear around the estimate. Estimates and confidence
intervals for other parameters, including the shoot yield at no P addition to the soil, were obtained by reparameterising
the model to the value of the key parameter
using R and GenStat 16th Edition (VSN International,
UK). Differences between the critical P concentrations,
the maximum yield (or asymptote) and the zero
P yields were tested by considering the estimates and
approximate standard errors for each measure simultaneously,
and testing for significant pairwise differences.
Significance was determined by calculating a
standardised difference that weighted the two contributing
standard errors. Values greater than two standard
errors were considered significantly different
(P = 0.05). No adjustment was made for multiple
comparisons."*

I dont know how to apply this myself and use it in R. Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: I could probably answer this easily if I only knew what a "critical value" is in Michelis-Menten kinetics. Could you please explain that?

Comment: Critical value is the amount of phosphorus (P) needed to achieve 90% of maximum yield. 100% is when phosphorus is no longer limiting plant growth. Farmers aim for 90% rather than 100% to avoid excess use. So I assume that Vmax in the Mechaelis Menton equation is maximum yield and I need to know how much P is need to achieve 90 % of that. Then to some how test statistically if the critical value is different between species. I have added an example in the post from a published paper.

Comment: I have calculted the critical value (CV) which is appernelty just 0.9 of KM.       m1= Yarloop (CV =103.365) 
m2= Dinninup (CV=56.862)
m3= Seaton Park (CV=29.592)
m4= Riverina (CV=103.257)

Comment: So what I have to do now is find out how to test if these values are statistically different from each other.

Answer (score 1):

> The critical external P requirement of each species was defined as the
>   amount of P applied to achieve 90 % of maximum yield.

I would first reparameterize the Michaelis-Menten model to this:

V = Vmax * (9 * [S]) / (K + 9 * [S])

Thus, if [S] equals K you get V = Vmax * 0.9, so K is then the desired critical value. You cannot simply use 0.9 * K with the original parameterization because there K is the substrate concentration that results in 0.5 * Vmax.

Then I would use the nlme package to test if the parameters depend on the cultivar.

First we fit a simple `nls` model to get decent starting values:

```
fit0 <- nls(shoot ~ Vm * (9*P) / (K + 9*P), data = DF, start = list(Vm = 2.2, K = 20))
coef(fit0)
```

Then we fit the same model with the `gnls` function:

```
library(nlme)

fit1 <- gnls(shoot ~ Vm * (9*P) / (K + 9*P), data = DF, 
             params = Vm + K ~ 1, start = as.list(coef(fit0)), na.action = na.omit)
```

Now, we stratify Vmax by cultivar:

```
fit2 <- gnls(shoot ~ Vm * (9*P) / (K + 9*P), data = DF, 
             params = list(Vm ~ cultivar, K~ 1), start = c(coef(fit0)[1], 0, 0, 0, coef(fit0)[2]), 
             na.action = na.omit)
```

And finally, we stratify both Vmax and K:

```
fit3 <- gnls(shoot ~ Vm * (9*P) / (K + 9*P), data = DF, 
             params = list(Vm + K ~ cultivar), start = c(coef(fit0)[1], 0, 0, 0, coef(fit0)[2], 0, 0, 0), 
             na.action = na.omit)
```

We can now create an ANOVA table comparing these models:

```
anova(fit1, fit2, fit3)
#     Model df       AIC       BIC    logLik   Test   L.Ratio p-value
#fit1     1  3  10.04295 17.113078 -2.021476                         
#fit2     2  6 -13.14363  0.996625 12.571814 1 vs 2 29.186579  <.0001
#fit3     3  9 -15.21449  5.995893 16.607243 2 vs 3  8.070859  0.0446
```

Here we see that stratifying Vmax improves the fit a lot. Additionally stratifying K (the critical value) results in a significant improvement but it's a very weak significance.

If you are interested in pairwise comparisons, do the last fit using subsets of two cultivars from your data:

```
fitab <- gnls(shoot ~ Vm * (9*P) / (K + 9*P), data = DF[DF$cultivar %in% c("Dinninup", "Yarloop"),], 
              params = list(Vm + K ~ cultivar), start = c(coef(fit0)[1], 0, coef(fit0)[2], 0), 
              na.action = na.omit)
summary(fitab)$tTable

#                        Value  Std.Error   t-value      p-value
#Vm.(Intercept)      1.9274407  0.1528903 12.606688 9.083261e-15
#Vm.cultivarYarloop  0.5159043  0.2486091  2.075163 4.517663e-02
#K.(Intercept)      56.8551277 18.7477563  3.032636 4.476802e-03
#K.cultivarYarloop  46.5081185 30.3802161  1.530869 1.345429e-01
```

The last row contains the relevant p-value. You'd do the same for all other pairwise comparisons and use the `p.adjust` function to adjust p-values for the multiple comparisons.

There is an important issue with your data: you do not have good data coverage around the critical values, most of your data is far below them. `coef(fit3)` tells us that the critical values are: 57, (57 + 46), (57 - 27), (57 + 47).

Comment: At the end of my post there is a typo, the critical value is 9*KM, not 0.9*KM.